# Can I use library abstractions in python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am using:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
```

to navigate around directories. All cool. However, I am running on windows 7 which of course has the library abstraction.  So for example the picture library might map to `c:\users\me` and `c:\users\share`
Is there any way I can use this library abstraction with python?

Comment: well if you just add an "r'" in front python sorts it out; 
like file=r'C:\users\me'

Comment: If you can do `os.listdir()` on a library abstraction you can use `os.walk()` on it too.

Comment: @BHM: I don't think the `r` is the issue here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think the issue is that you can't do either `listdir` _or_ `walk`—that is, at the filesystem level, there's no directory representing the library, with a bunch of subdirectories (or symlinks or junctions or whatever) pointing at the actual directories. But I could be wrong, because I've never used this feature. (Reading http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-7-libraries-–-and-why-you-want-them/ it looks like the underlying storage is probably some kind of database, not just a list of directories.)

Comment: @abarnert: I don't have *any* windows setup here to even try. But if you cannot use `os.listdir()` on these, then you cannot `os.walk()` either.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm wrong about how this feature works (I don't actually have a Win7 box in front of me), you will have to access the Windows Shell APIs in order to access libraries.

Reading [Introducing Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx#id0370007) from MSDN Magazine, it seems pretty clear that apps that just deal with the filesystem will see a library as just a regular directory, and not even have any indication of the various scattered directories that make up the library. Unless you always stick to the fancy file-chooser dialogs to get all paths (in which case the user sees libraries, but always ends up picking a specific folder, so you don't have to deal with libraries), you have to explicitly use the shell APIs.

I think you want to start at [Windows Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the dev guide and [IShellLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the reference.

These are obviously COM APIs, so you probably want to use [`win32com`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to access them from Python. (You could use `ctypes` and deal with the COM stuff C-style, but you really don't want to.) It's possible that someone has already wrapped up these COM objects in a nice Python interface—I didn't find anything in quick PyPI and ActiveState searches, but you might want to try a more serious search.

Alternatively, of course, you could use IronPython and use the .NET APIs instead of the native ones.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent build of Pywin32 (218) has support for the shell library interfaces:

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from win32com import storagecon
import os

kfm = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_KnownFolderManager, None,
        pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IKnownFolderManager)
libs_folder = kfm.GetFolder(shell.FOLDERID_Libraries)
libs_path = libs_folder.GetPath()

for lib_file in os.listdir(libs_path):
    if os.path.splitext(lib_file)[1] == '.library-ms':
        print lib_file
        i = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(os.path.join(libs_path, lib_file),
                                              None, shell.IID_IShellItem)
        lib = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_ShellLibrary, None,
                                         pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC, shell.IID_IShellLibrary)
        lib.LoadLibraryFromItem(i, storagecon.STGM_READ)
        for folder in lib.GetFolders():
            print '\t' + folder.GetDisplayName(shellcon.SHGDN_FORPARSING)
```