# Copying files usingwin32com.shell pidl reference in Windows - to copy picture files off an iPhone

Tags: python, ios, iphone, win32com

I've been trying to find a way to copy files off an iPhone but despite being able to list files within it using win32com.shell GetDisplayNameOf and BindToObject, I can't seem to find any way of copying files using only the pidl reference.

Unfortunately when the iPhone is connected to Windows it doesn't mount as a drive letter, requiring you to use the PIDL reference rather than a full path. However after much Googling, I can't seem to find a way of copying using only the PIDL reference.

"path = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl)" seems to be a potential option to find a filesystem path from a PIDL, however as the iPhone doesn't mount to a filesystem path, this always returns an error when given a PIDL value.

Example code I've used so far (taken from [How can I iterate across the photos on my connected iPhone from Windows 7 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593315/how-can-i-iterate-across-the-photos-on-my-connected-iphone-from-windows-7-in-pyt)):

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()

for pidl in desktop:
    if desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "This PC":
        # path = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl)
        print path
        break

folder = desktop.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
for pidl in folder:
     if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "My iPhone":
         break

folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "Internal Storage":
        break
        
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "DCIM":
        break

# Each of the image folders
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
for pidl in folder:
    # print folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)

    files = folder.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

    for curfile in files:
        current_file = folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) + "\\" + files.GetDisplayNameOf(curfile, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)
        folder.BindToObject(pidl, )
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Key references I've used so far:
Example code that correctly reads the filesystem using PIDLs: [How can I iterate across the photos on my connected iPhone from Windows 7 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593315/how-can-i-iterate-across-the-photos-on-my-connected-iphone-from-windows-7-in-pyt)

Example of how to list files off an iPhon, but no details of how to copy them: https://github.com/dblume/list-photos-on-phone/blob/master/list-photos-on-phone.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure of the links to stuff. But I have been able to copy files once I have a PIDL. You have to create a ShellItem of the file and the destination. Then use the IFileOperation. I think it was mostly a lot of googling and looking up the microsoft [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Anyway here's the code. Hopefully it helps!

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pythoncom
#fo is the folder IShellFolder object
#dsk is the destination IShellFolder object
#fi is the PIDL of the item you wish to copy (eg. the photo on your iPhone)

fidl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(fo) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object
didl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(dsk) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object

si = shell.SHCreateShellItem(fidl, None, fi) #Create a ShellItem of the source file
dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromIDList(didl)

#Python IFileOperation
pfo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation,None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL,shell.IID_IFileOperation)
pfo.SetOperationFlags(shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
pfo.CopyItem(si, dst, "Destination Name.jpg") # Schedule an operation to be performed
success = pfo.PerformOperations() #perform operation
```

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the above information, with it I was able to make a python implementation for  moving photos from iPhone X to Windows10 PC. Key functions below

```
# imports probably needed
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from win32com.propsys import propsys
import pythoncom

# Recursive function to browse into a non filesystem path
def recurse_and_get_ishellfolder(base_ishellfolder, path):
    splitted_path = path.split("\\", 1)

    for pidl in base_ishellfolder:
        if base_ishellfolder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == splitted_path[0]:
            break

    folder = base_ishellfolder.BindToObject(pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

    if len(splitted_path) > 1:
        # More to recurse
        return recurse_and_get_ishellfolder(folder, splitted_path[1])
    else:
        return folder


# How to move non filesystem file to filesystem patj
def move_file_by_pidl_to_path(src_ishellfolder, src_pidl, dst_path, dst_filename):
    pidl_folder_dst, flags = shell.SHILCreateFromPath(dst_path, 0)
    dst_ishellfolder = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder().BindToObject(pidl_folder_dst, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

    fidl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(src_ishellfolder)  # Grab the PIDL from the folder object
    didl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(dst_ishellfolder)  # Grab the PIDL from the folder object

    si = shell.SHCreateShellItem(fidl, None, src_pidl)  # Create a ShellItem of the source file
    dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromIDList(didl)

    pfo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL, shell.IID_IFileOperation)
    pfo.SetOperationFlags(shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | shellcon.FOF_SILENT | shellcon.FOF_NOERRORUI)
    pfo.MoveItem(si, dst, dst_filename) # Schedule an operation to be performed
    pfo.PerformOperations()
    return not pfo.GetAnyOperationsAborted()


# Bonus: get file modification datetime for a non filesystem file
DATE_PROP_KEY = propsys.PSGetPropertyKeyFromName("System.DateModified")
DATE_PROP_PARSE_STR = '%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S.%f' # not sure bout the f modifier but it does not really matter
def getmodified_datetime_by_pidl(src_ishellfolder, src_pidl):
    fidl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(src_ishellfolder)  # Grab the PIDL from the folder object
    si = shell.SHCreateShellItem(fidl, None, src_pidl)  # Create a ShellItem of the source file
    ps = propsys.PSGetItemPropertyHandler(si)
    date_str = ps.GetValue(DATE_PROP_KEY).ToString()
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, DATE_PROP_PARSE_STR)


# Example photo moving main logic
def move_files():
    main_folder = recurse_and_get_ishellfolder(shell.SHGetDesktopFolder(), "This Pc\\path\\to\\DCIM")

    for photo_folder_pidl in main_folder:
        folder_name = main_folder.GetDisplayNameOf(photo_folder_pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)
        folder = main_folder.BindToObject(photo_folder_pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
        for pidl in folder:
            child_name = folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)

            file_mod_date = getmodified_datetime_by_pidl(folder, pidl)
            if not older_than_datetime or file_mod_date < older_than_datetime:
                print("Transferring file: " + child_name)
                move_file_by_pidl_to_path(...)
            else:
                print("Skipping too recent file: " + child_name)
```

Full script for moving photos:
https://gitlab.com/lassi.niemisto/iphone-photo-dump

EDIT: Key parts from linked implementation copied here as code

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I would think a functional implementation example would help as a complementary answer. Copypasting the code from gitlab does not make sense to me, all the relevant knowledge is already posted here.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31100261)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, and thanks to [@Stephen Brodie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14726622/stephen-brodie)'s answer, I successed to copy a picture to my PC with windows10.

> [@Stephen Brodie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14726622/stephen-brodie) menstioned:
>
> ```
> from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
> import pythoncom
> #fo is the folder IShellFolder object
> #dsk is the destination IShellFolder object
> #fi is the PIDL of the item you wish to copy (eg. the photo on your iPhone)
>
> fidl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(fo) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object
> didl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(dsk) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object
>
> si = shell.SHCreateShellItem(fidl, None, fi) #Create a ShellItem of the source file
> dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromIDList(didl)
>
> #Python IFileOperation
> pfo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation,None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL,shell.IID_IFileOperation)
> pfo.SetOperationFlags(shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
> pfo.CopyItem(si, dst, "Destination Name.jpg") # Schedule an operation to be performed
> success = pfo.PerformOperations() #perform operation
> ```

### Below is my code according to [@Stephen Brodie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14726622/stephen-brodie)'s.

Source file: \Computer\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\100APPLE\IMG_0199.JPG
Destination folder: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myFolder\savedImages

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pythoncom

# get the PIDL of source file and the ShellObject of the folder in which source file is
# and the PIDL of the folder

desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
for pidl in desktop:
    if desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "Computer":
        pidl_get = pidl
        break
folder = desktop.BindToObject(pidl_get, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "Apple iPhone":
        pidl_get = pidl
        break
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl_get, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "Internal Storage":
        pidl_get = pidl
        break
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl_get, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "DCIM":
        pidl_get = pidl
        break
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl_get, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "100APPLE":
        pidl_get = pidl
        break
folderPIDL = pidl_get
folder = folder.BindToObject(pidl_get, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
```

NOW we have

`folderPIDL`: PIDL of the folder in which the source file is
`folder`: the ShellObject of the folder in which the source file is

```
for pidl in folder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "IMG_0199.JPG":
        imgPIDL = pidl

# imgPIDL: PIDL of the source file
```

And we get `imgPIDL`.
(**Remember to enable windows10 to show extensions in File Explorer.**
Otherwise, `folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)` will show "IMG_0199"
instead of "IMG_0199.JPG".)

```
# then get the ShellObject of Destination folder

for pidl in desktop:
    if desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "myFolder":
        pidl_dst = pidl
        break
dstFolder = desktop.BindToObject(pidl_dst, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

for pidl in dstFolder:
    if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) == "savedImages":
        pidl_dst = pidl
        break
dstFolder = folder.BindToObject(pidl_dst, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder)
```

All we need for copy file are 4 var: folderPIDL, folder, imgPIDL and dstFolder

## Start to Copy file (@Stephen Brodie's code)

```
fidl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(folder) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object
didl = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(dstFolder) #Grab the PIDL from the folder object

si = shell.SHCreateShellItem(fidl, None, imgPIDL) #Create a ShellItem of the source file
dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromIDList(didl)

#Python IFileOperation
pfo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation,None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL,shell.IID_IFileOperation)
pfo.SetOperationFlags(shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
pfo.CopyItem(si, dst, "Destination Name.jpg") # Schedule an operation to be performed
success = pfo.PerformOperations() #perform operation
```

And success!!
At first, I tried to skip `fidl` and `didl`, and just used `si` and `dst`. I failed. The error message said last line `pfo.PerformOperations()` cannot run. Maybe `SHGetIDListFromObject()` is essential for changing ShellObject to IDList.

Besides, my PC show Chinese character "本機" instead of "Computer". All I need is to change "Computer" to "本機" in the codes above.

Comment: This is an exact copy of [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842087/354577). [Please don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627).

Comment: It's ok for me not to copy, but I want others who have the same problem can find out the solution and the implementation. What is the proper way to post and redirect others seeing this post to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593315/how-can-i-iterate-across-the-photos-on-my-connected-iphone-from-windows-7-in-pyt/72842087#72842087)?

Comment: Please read [the post I linked to in my first comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627). It outlines several things you can do.